# I would like to merge the non-na rows of a right table to a left table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a list of dataframes that I am seeking to merge into a singular dataframe. Each of the dataframes contains the same number of rows and columns, as well as the same column names. However, some of the dataframes contain many  values with a few non-NA values. I would like to go through the list of df's and merge the non  values of the right table into the left table, whether the left table has  values at that index or not.

My data appears like the following

```
A B  C       A B  C
1 t 5.0      1 t <NA>
2 n 2.0      2 n <NA>
3 z 3.0      3 z 2.0
4 m <NA>     4 m 4.0
5 j 1.0      5 j <NA>
```

I attempted to merge the list of dataframes using pd.concat and filtering conditions contained inside of the expression:

```
table_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
merged_table = pd.concat(table_of_dfs[i].merge(table_of_dfs[i+1][~table_of_dfs[i+1].isnull().T.any().T], on=['A','B','C'], how='left') for i in range(len(table_of_dfs) - 1))
```

My desired result:

```
A B  C 
1 t 5.0  
2 n 2.0     
3 z 2.0     
4 m 4.0  
5 j 1.0
```

My actual result:

```
    A B  C  
    1 t 5.0  
    2 n 2.0    
    3 z 3.0    
    4 m <NA> 
    5 j 1.0 
    6 t <NA>
    7 n <NA>
    8 z 2.0
    9 m 4.0
   10 j <NA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and `reduce` from `functools` module:

```
from functools import reduce
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

>>> reduce(lambda dfA, dfB: dfB.combine_first(dfA), dfs)
   A  B    C
0  1  t  5.0
1  2  n  2.0
2  3  z  2.0
3  4  m  4.0
4  5  j  6.0
5  6  p  9.0
```

Data:

```
>>> df1
   A  B    C
0  1  t  5.0
1  2  n  2.0
2  3  z  3.0
3  4  m  NaN
4  5  j  1.0

>>> df2
   A  B    C
0  1  t  NaN
1  2  n  NaN
2  3  z  2.0
3  4  m  4.0
4  5  j  NaN

>>> df3
   A  B    C
0  1  t  5.0
1  2  n  NaN
2  3  z  2.0
3  4  m  4.0
4  5  j  6.0
5  6  p  9.0  # added a new row
```

Comment: I think it's the other way around, nice one though ;) +1

Comment: I attempted this solution. It's supposed to iteratively add more non NA values as time progresses I'm assuming. Well, I've put in the function as follows `merged_df = [df[i+1].combine_first(df[i]) for i in range(len(table_of_dfs)-1)]`. So, I'm supposed to replace the values from 1 into 2, eventually all of the values are supposed to be located in the last index. Instead most of them are still <NA> values.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check if this suits your need please?

Comment: This works, could you provide a small paragraph of explanation beneath the bottom as to why this solution works? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call you dataframes df1 and df2. You can use `where` to replace the NaN values:

```
df2['C'] = df1['C'].where(df2['C'].isna(), df2['C'])
```

Comment: It does not appear that this solution works.